# javascript variable declarations after return statement

Tags: javascript

I was looking at some minified javascript code (from github), and the code has a block that looks like

```
h = function(a, b, c, d) {
        var e, h, i, j, k, l, m = this;
        return i = $("#js-frame-loading-template").clone().show(), l = c === "back" ? 350 : 500, j = i.find(".js-frame-loading-spinner").hide() // more stuff here
```

I'm curious why/how this code works since there are variable declarations after the return statement

Comment: Read more about the comma operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator. In short: Everything to the right of the `return` statement is one expression and the value of the last "sub-expression" is returned. There are no variable declarations in that line btw, only assignments.

Comment: @FelixKling thanks for clarifying. Can you add this an answer so it can be upvoted/accepted?

Comment: I was hoping to find a duplicate (I'm sure it exists), but well... ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[Let me introduce you to the comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator).**

Everything to the right of the `return` statement is one expression, consisting of multiple "sub-expressions", separated by commas:

```
return a, b, c, d;
```

Each sub-expression is evaluated, from left to right, and the value of the last one is the result of the whole expression. I.e. the result of the last expression is returned in this case (the results of evaluating `d` and whatever hides in `// more stuff here` in your example).

It's a "trick" to squeeze multiple expressions into one.

---

Nitpick:

> [...] since there are variable declarations after the return statement

There are no variable *declarations* in that line, only assignment expressions. You could not have a `var` statement (a variable declaration) there because the comma operator (and the `return` statement), only works with expressions, not statements.